# How do I set javascrip to disable selection after timer reached 0?

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the selection box, after the countdown timer reached 0, is it possible to do it in javascript? I'm struggling to put the functions in the timer function...

```
<html>
<p id="demo">10</p>
<button onclick="clock()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>

<div class="box">
    <p>Cell Background Colour:  
         <select id="bgcolour" class="color" name="cbc">
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="white" selected>White</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Above is html, this is the javascript.

```
<script>
var selection = document.getElementByClass("box");
var timesUp = document.getElementsById('c')[0];

timesUp.addEventListener('c', function(event) {
    button.disabled = !button.disabled;
});

var myTimer;

function clock() 
{
  myTimer = setInterval(countclock, 1000);
  var c = 10;
  function countclock()
 {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;

    if (c == 0) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        timesUp();
    }
 }
}

function timesUp() {
    alert("Times up");

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `disabled` property of your dropdown to `true`,

```
if (c == 0) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        document.getElementById("bgcolour").disabled = true;
        timesUp();
}
```

Comment: still can't get it to run :(

Comment: and it goes over negative, i want it to stop at 0

Comment: ok nvm i got it to work! thank you for the help!! so those var event listener are not needed!